# What is a red bone in skeleton in Unreal Viewer?

Tags: maya, unreal-engine4

I'm learning Unreal Engine and Maya. I've imported my character mesh and skeleton into Unreal. It mostly looks fine, but I see a red bone in the Unreal skeleton Viewer.

What does this red bone indicate?

[image]

Comment: I believe it's the root bone that goes from the origin to the first bone in the hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `Root Bone` of a skeleton.

The pivot point of a Skeletal Mesh is always located at the `Root Bone`/`Root Joint` of the skeleton. This means it doesn't matter where the root of the skeleton is located within the scene. It will be thought as if it is at the World Origin (0,0,0) when exporting from a 3D modeling application.

Comment: Is it what you were looking for?